# Finding random numbers in a range that have different minimal distances between each other

Tags: c++, random

I'm writing a simulation program "Core War". I need to generate random positions for x amount of programs in a given range of memory. They will always fit in the memory.

The programs have some amount of lines. I need to randomly place them in the memory, so that they don't overlap with each other. I'm looking for the starting line position:

Example - for the inputs:

```
memorySize = 50;
programCount = 3;
programLengths = [3, 7, 4]
```

The function would have to output 3 positions for the 3 program lengths, which:

- are from 0 to 49
- cannot in any way overlap with another program, for example if the output would be
  `[0, 2, 20]`, the first and the second program would overlap, because the length of the first program is 3 lines, which means that the last line would be on index 2. The second program would overlap the first.

I tried making a function that does that for 2 programs, but it was too complicated and I just set the first one to zero and randomly picked the other one:

```
std::pair<size_t, size_t> findStartingPositions()
{
    // first.size and second.size are lengths of programs
    size_t posFirst = 0;

    std::mt19937 mt_rand(time(0));
    size_t posSecond = mt_rand() % (MEMORY_SIZE - second.size - first.size);
    posSecond += first.size;
    return { posFirst, posSecond };
};
```

But I'd like a better and more scalable approach.

---

These are the available variables:

```
std::vector<Program> programs; // program[0].size() returns the length of the first program
size_t memorySize;
```

---

If possible, a mersenne twister answer would be best.

Comment: The total length of three programs is 14. So the first program must start somewhere between 0 and 35, to still leave room for the others. Pick a random number in that range. Once picked, you will know how much memory you still have remaining, and how long the remaining programs are in total - repeat the same algorithm for the second program, and so on.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I'm not sure what you mean by that. Could you write a whole example (for the 2nd and 3rd program)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose all the programs have size 1, then, you might simply shuffle the whole arena.

Now to handle different size, just consider first instruction and

- reduce arena size by length of programs.
- [`shuffle`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) the whole (small) arena.
- rebuild the full arena (insert instruction after the first one)

Answer (score 0):

In the example problem, there are 36 lines that will *not* be in programs, remaining empty.

Randomly shuffle the 5 programs to determine their order, and then randomly choose the 3 positions at which they will be inserted into the list of 36 empty lines.  Note that a list of 36 lines has 37 positions to choose from.